# Assignment of read-only location while using set_union to merge two sets

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am trying to combine two set to one set, but when I use the simplest example, a error:`assignment of read-only location '__result.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<int>()'` the code is:

```
set<int> a;
set<int> b;
int x[4] = {0,1,2,3};int y[5] = {1,2,4,6,9};
a.insert(x,x+4);
b.insert(y,y+5);
set<int> c;
set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), c.begin());
```

So am I writing wrong? What should I do if I want to merge two `set` and use a new `set` to contain the elements?

The error calls from this line: `set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), c.begin());`

Comment: It might be helpful to know what line of code is responsible for the compiler diagnostic message.

Comment: try to replace `c.begin()` with std::inserter(c,c.begin())

Comment: the code `std::inserter(c,c.begin())` works! Thank you! So which attribute does `inserter` change?

Comment: It provides an output iterator that inserts into the set. Assigning to `c.begin()` an onward requires there to be something in the set already. Not to mention, you aren't allowed to assign to a set member via iterator anyway (it can break the set invariant).

Comment: maybe not related, but why `x+4` and `y+5` used as second parameters for `a.insert` and `b.insert` It seems to me that you are pointing to some nowhereland memory, shouldn't it be x+3 and y+4 to point to the last element of the two arrays? (just asking, maybe I'm completely missing how that overload of insert work)

Comment: @GianPaolo by convention, c++ uses half open ranges. "end" is one beyond the last element of the array

Comment: thanks, @Caleth, This is quite intuitive when you use an iterator from a container (someContainer.end()), it's weird to me with plane array such `int x[4]` (pointing to the first memory location after allocated memory of the array, which in many case is UB). but if that's the way it works, ok for me as well!

Comment: @GianPaolo You can *compare to* a pointer one beyond the end, you can't dereference it. e.g. `for (int * p = a; p != a+4; ++p) { std::cout << *p; }` is fine. Iterators are "pointer like" in, rather than the other way around

Comment: @Caleth, that's make sense actually. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::set<int>::iterator` isn't an [OutputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator), so it isn't suitable for use as the fifth argument of `std::set_union`. You probably mean to insert into `c`, so a suitable iterator is [`std::inserter(c,c.begin())`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter).

```
set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(c,c.begin()));
```

An OutputIterator is one that can have its pointed-to values assigned to, and a `std::insert_iterator<std::set<int>>` achieves this by returning a proxy object, that inserts into the set when assigned to, rather than a `int&`

Alternatively, if you know how many items will result (or are prepared to overallocate), you could use a different container's begin, such as `std::array<int, 7>`, or a `std::vector<int>` whose size was sufficient to contain the 7 elements resulting from the union.

```
std::vector<int> d(a.size() + b.size(), 0); // preallocate enough
std::vector<int>::iterator end = std::set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), d.begin());
d.erase(end, d.end()); // clean up any excess elements not from `a` or `b`
```